# Framelayout becomes invisible but still occupies space

Tags: android, visibility, android-framelayout

I have an xml file where I manage the visibility of a framelayout from the java side. the xml have 2 framelayout as button on a linearlayout . the orientation is horizental. Once I hide the first button on the right , the left one stay at his place but it should move to the right.

any ideas how to fix this ?

here is my xml code :

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/float_button"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/icon2" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/float_button"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/icon1"
            >

        </ImageView>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

my java code :

```
@Override
    public void notifyLayoutReady() {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (showUserOption("option1"))
                    mBtn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (showUserOption("option2"))
                    mBtn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: use else statement to hide again that view

if (showUserOption("option1"))
                    mBtn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); else{mBtn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
                if (showUserOption("option2"))
                    mBtn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else{mBtn2.setVisibility(View.Gone);}

Answer (score 1):

Seems like while clicking on button and setting visibility you are using `View.INVISIBLE` , try using `View.GONE` for the same.

Comment: by default it is gone , on the java side i call View.VISIBLE but it still taking space

Comment: You don't hide first layout, when second statement is true. Use `if(){} else {}` and in else let hide this layout.

Comment: thanks that worked but I don't understand , if it was already gone on the xml why it should be called again on the java code ?

Comment: there is always two stages for any condition. if(){} and else{}... Now when you are showing something on 1 case then on other case it should be hidden. otherwise conditions will get misleading while trying same scenarios more than one time.

Answer (score 0):

there are two way mange it used gone to instand of invisiable..

```
        android:visibility="invisible"
```

or to set gravity to layout like below..

```
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
```

both frame layout because gone is remove all space and invisiable only hide the view but space is remaining.